# MYSQL storing multiple images

Tags: php, mysql

I have a web page where users can upload articles with images on them. There is not limit on the amount of images a user can upload with their article. Each row in a MySQL database represents one article of many. What is the best way to store all these images. I know I would use BLOBS/LONGBLOBS but if I have no control over the amount of images a user uploads I can't just insert 50 columns for different images and hope they upload less than 50. What is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do this is to create a table with images that references the article so it will leave you with a database like this:

[image: Database Diagram]

The table creation script for `Images` would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `Images` (
    `ImageID` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `ArticleID` bigint NOT NULL,
    `Image` longblob NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`ImageID`)
);
ALTER TABLE `Images` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_Images` FOREIGN KEY (`ArticleID`) REFERENCES `Articles`(`ArticleID`);
```

Now all you have to do is insert an image into `Images` together with the `ArticleID` it belongs to.

Comment: Good answer. Although I'd like to point out for OP's sake that storing images as blobs is not as efficient as storing relative paths to where they exist on the filesystem.. It is an inefficient structure to query a database for hundreds or thousands of kilobytes worth of raw image data on n number of images, and very slow compared to just fetching a list of paths to said images.